# Adding c++17 constexpr and other improvements to a C++ Java Enum emulator

Tags: java, c++, enums, c++17, constexpr

A couple of years ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777054/c-java-like-enum-header-compiler-error) using an example to simulate a rich Java like enum class in C++0x.   I am asking for suggestions on how to improve the design with a goal towards (1) machieving constexpr and (2) avoiding the manual steps where I effectively (a) declare the nested enum values,  (b) declare and hopefully soon constexpr initialize the static fields, and (c) initialize the set of strict weak ordered enums.  I wonder if templates may help in this area.

The code is pretty straight forward and is shown in the following [**coliru live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ceb925c849f60b47) demo.

Specifically, I wanted to be able to:

**- Switch on values.**

The code snippet below shows how this works, the restriction was that instead of switching on the BetterEnum::EnumValue1, I had to instead switch on the nested enum value - this is not obvious but it uses the integral cast operator:

```
//! Integral cast operator for switch statements (cast to named enum).
constexpr operator const Value() const noexcept {
    return mValue;
}
```

I am not sure how to work around this restriction.

```
BetterEnum val = BetterEnum::EnumValue1;

switch (val) {
case BetterEnum::enumvalue1:
    std::cout << BetterEnum::EnumValue1.getStringVal() << std::endl;
    break;
case BetterEnum::enumvalue2:
    std::cout << BetterEnum::EnumValue2.getStringVal() << std::endl;
    break;
case BetterEnum::enumvalue3:
    std::cout << BetterEnum::EnumValue3.getStringVal() << std::endl;
    break;
default:
    ;
}
std::cout << BetterEnum::EnumValue1 << std::endl;
```

**- Perform string based enum lookup.**

```
//! Lookup Enum by <code>aStringVal</code>.
static BetterEnum valueOf(const std::string_view aStringVal) {
    for (const auto& rNext : getValues()) {
        if (rNext.getStringVal() == aStringVal) {
            return rNext;
        }
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument(
        std::string("Illegal Argument: ") + std::string(aStringVal));
}
```

**- Perform value based enum lookup.**

```
//! Lookup Enum by <code>aValue</code>.
static BetterEnum valueOf(const Value aValue) {
    for (const auto& next : getValues()) {
        if (next.mValue == aValue) {
            return next;
        }
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument(
        std::string("Illegal Argument: ") + std::to_string(aValue));
}
```

**- Implement as header only.**

I recently added support for this by using [inline const initializers](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2205/7-features-of-c17-that-will-simplify-your-code/inline-variables) at the bottom of the class.

```
inline const BetterEnum BetterEnum::EnumValue1(BetterEnum::enumvalue1, "EnumValue1"sv);
inline const BetterEnum BetterEnum::EnumValue2(BetterEnum::enumvalue2, "EnumValue2"sv);
inline const BetterEnum BetterEnum::EnumValue3(BetterEnum::enumvalue3, "EnumValue3"sv);
```

**- Add constexpr support.**

Although partially added - use of the `std::set<T>` restricts the number of members that I can make constexpr as this would require std::set to be constexpr (which it is not, although `std::array<T, N>` is but that doesn't guarantee the uniqueness of the emum entries ordered via strict weak ordering via the `operator<()` operator).

My original non-constexpr design used strings - I had to change these to string_views to the constexpr constructor - however I am not sure how to avoid the `using namespace std::literals;` in the header file to avoid polluting the namespace for every file that includes this header.

**- Add stream insertion operator support.**

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BetterEnum& rhs) {
    os << rhs.getStringVal();
    return os;
}
```

We have moved on a few years and are currently at c++17 with C++20 looming on the horizon.  I wanted to see if I could improve on the the class which I have been dragging along on various projects over the years.

Specifically I would like to know if there is some way to make the static members constexpr.  C++17 introduced the notion of improved [static variable initialization](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2205/7-features-of-c17-that-will-simplify-your-code/inline-variables).  This allowed me to improve the class to a header only implementation, however if I attempt to initialize the static class members inside the class definition

```
class BetterEnum final {
public:
    enum Value {
        enumvalue1, enumvalue2, enumvalue3
    };

    static constexpr BetterEnum EnumValue1 = BetterEnum(BetterEnum::enumvalue1, "EnumValue1"sv);
    static constexpr BetterEnum EnumValue2 = BetterEnum(BetterEnum::enumvalue2, "EnumValue2"sv);
    static constexpr BetterEnum EnumValue3 = BetterEnum(BetterEnum::enumvalue3, "EnumValue3"sv);

...
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
main.cpp:15:95: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class BetterEnum'
     static constexpr BetterEnum EnumValue1 = BetterEnum(BetterEnum::enumvalue1, "EnumValue1"sv);
                                                                                               ^
main.cpp:9:7: note: definition of 'class BetterEnum' is not complete until the closing brace
 class BetterEnum final {
```

Comment: Upvoted for reminding me why A) I hate C++ and prefer programming in Java and B) I am really jealous about many of the cool things you can do in C++.

Comment: I used to be the other way around but the evolving standard has made me change my mind

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the C++ code or the explanation in the link. `Previously only methods/functions could be specified as inline, but now you can do the same with variables` Is that what you want to emulate?  Some other feature?  The only way to emulate it 100% is to use C++.

Comment: Good point, I am using C++ and I made a slight tweak based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432283/c-static-constexpr-field-with-incomplete-type which looks promising